# Mean of random variable given a "big" variance

Tags: random-variables, variance, means

Let $X$ be a (discrete) random variable that takes values in $[0,1]$ and such that $\textrm{var}(X)$ is big in some sense like
$$\textrm{var}(X)\ge\varepsilon$$
Can the mean $\mathbb{E}(X)$ be bounded from below?
The resaoning is that, if $\textrm{var}(X)$ is "big", then $X$ takes many different values, so it takes at least one high value and thus the sum is at least as big as that value.

However, I haven't been able to prove anything yet even if I use Markov's and Chebyshev's inequalities.

Many thanks!

Comment: Why would many different values of $X$ yield a larger variance? The expectation is defined by $E(X)=\sum_k p_k x_k$, where $p_k$ is the probability of the value $x_k$. The sum is not as big as the largest value of $x_k$, you have to take the probability into account. And since the mean is obviously in $[0,1]$, many different values of $X$ means many are closer to the mean, hence reducing the variance.

Comment: For two different values, you can compute the variance explicitly. Say $p(X=0)=1-p$ and $p(X=1)=p$, then $E(X)=p$ and $E[(X-E(X)^2]=p^2(1-p)+p(1-p)^2=p(1-p)$.  That's the variance, and it's easy to prove that it can't be larger than $1/4$, reached for $p=1/2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments, for a   distribution of variance $\epsilon$ supported on $\{0,1\}$, the mean $p$ solves $$p-p^2=\epsilon \,. \tag{*}$$
Let $$p_1= \frac{1-\sqrt{1-4\epsilon}}2 \in [0, 1/2]$$ be the smaller solution of $(*)$.

Consider a  random variable $X$ supported in $[0,1]$, of mean $m$ and variance $\epsilon$. We have
$$m^2+\epsilon=E[X^2] \le E[X]=m\,,$$
so $m-m^2 \ge \epsilon $, whence $\epsilon \le 1/4$ and $m \ge p_1$.

Comment: Thanks! I deduced this right after posting the question